# Why to use delegation in ruby

Tags: ruby, delegates, delegation

Is there any good reason to use delegation over inheritance. I think all the things that can be done by delegation can be done by inheritance. Is my understanding of concept wrong. Does there exist a situation in which we are forced to use delegation in ruby? Can anyone please share real life example with me.

Comment: Personally I massively prefer delegation *over* inheritance, at least in Java and C#. It tends to be much easier to reason about, and give each type *one* thing to worry about, without considering which members different implementations might override and how they interact...

Comment: A beautiful explanation of this with example can be found in `Practical Object-Oriented Design in Ruby -by Sandi Metz`.

Answer (score 2):

Systems become complex when tight coupling exists than what is needed, so it is necessary to avoid connections between objects where possible. You do that using delegation. Delegation leads to highly re-usable classes and methods.

If my granny wants to buy a laptop, she can either just ask me to get a better one (delegate / low coupling) or she can get list of shops/sites from me and order it herself (and deal with delayed delivery, incorrect configuration etc).